# f:convertDateTime timezone doesnt apply

Tags: jsf, timezone, java-time

I'm using JSF 2.3.
I have a datatable with some items, each item has an offsetDateTime.
I want to display the datetime in an other timezone.

```
<p:column headerText="UpdateTime" sortBy="#{item.updateTimestamp}">
    <h:outputText value="#{item.updateTimestamp}">
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" timeZone="Europe/Brussels" type="offsetDateTime"/>
    </h:outputText>   
</p:column>
```

However for an input in UTC *2020-07-08T13:49:36.801693Z* for instance, my app will display 2020/07/08 13:49:36 (it should be 15:49:36 as it's "summer" in Belgium).

I know that we can't put dynamic values for timezone (omnifaces converter has been created to tackle this issue) but here it should work as the timeZone is a String that corresponds to a standard TZ id.

Thank for you help !

Comment: `type="offsetDateTime"`??? Documentation of [`convertDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/f/convertDateTime.html) says: *`type` - Specifies what contents the string value will be formatted to include, or parsed expecting. **Valid values are "date", "time", and "both"**. Default value is "date".*

Comment: in java 7, but JSF 2.3 relies on java 8. So you have more values
https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/doc/5.0/vdldoc/f/convertDateTime.html